# Required field validator in sapui5

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

I have four text fields with labels name, age, city and phone number.I have to validate it if it left empty. it should alert me to fill. How to validate a text field with required field validator in sapui5?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply write a function that get the textfields and checks their value.
This could look like this:

```
function validateTextFieldValues() {

    // this function gets the first textfield
    var nameTextField = sap.ui.getCore().byId("idOfTheTextFieldContaingTheName");
    //this function checks its value, you can insert more checks on the value
    if(nameTextField.getValue() === "") {
        alert("Please enter a name.");
    }

    // ...
    // the same for the other fields
}
```

Then you can bind the function on the button-click, for example when creating the button:

```
new sap.ui.commons.Button({
    // your buttonconfiguration
    click: function(){
        validateTextFieldValues();
    }
});
```

Additionally the `TextField` has an attribute called `valueState`.
In connection with its event `liveChange` there is the opportunity to validate the input while typing:

```
new sap.ui.commons.TextField({
    // your configuration
    liveChange: function(){
        if(this.getValue() === "")
            this.setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.Error);
        else
            this.setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.Success);
    }
});
```

<sub>(https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.ValueState.html)</sub>

Comment: Is there any API reference for validation in sapui5?

Comment: if (this.getValue().trim().length === 0){}

Comment: 1. Some UI5 control also has [setValueStateText()](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.InputBase.html#getValueStateText)  
2. Use [Data Types](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/0eac123bf7da42bb957cca46047e6556.html) plus [Handling Wrong User Input](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/c75861e33942410d9ac77322763db203.html) seems the built-in way of input handling, but I cannot see more benefit than custom error hanndling function.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate it on change of the field value itself as below

```
var oname = new sap.ui.commons.TextField({
id: 'input2',
change : function(){
       if(this.getValue()=='')
         alert("enter some value");
  }
});
```

Or you can write a function for validation on click of some button.

Answer (score 0):

Even using the required property will not help as UI5 does not puts any controls in forms tags. The required property sets an attribute

> aria-required=true

You can use jQuery to select all the aria-required elements and process them on any other controls event say press of button.

Below is sample code for the same.

```
var oBtn = new sap.ui.commons.Button();
    oBtn.attachPress(function(){
        var error;
        jQuery('input[aria-required=true]').each(function(){
            var oInput = sap.ui.getCore().byId(this.id);
            var val = oInput.getValue();
            if(!val){                   
                var sHtml = '<ul><li><strong> value is empty</li></ul>';
                var sValueState = '<strong>Error!</strong>';
                // Combine Input value, Error title and message into a Rich Tooltip
                var oTooltip = new sap.ui.commons.RichTooltip({ text: sHtml, valueStateText: sValueState});
                oInput.setTooltip(oTooltip);
                oInput.setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.Error);
                error = false;
            }else{
                oInput.setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.None);                   
                oInput.setTooltip(' ');
            }
        });
        if(error){
            return error;
        }
    });
```